# Writing a list to file function with filename and list as parameter

Tags: python, list, function, file

I'm trying to write a function such as the one below except it it'd take the list and filename as parameter. It's annoyingly basic and yet it escapes me.

```py
def write_list_to_file():
    wordlst = ["No", "Time", "for", "this"]
    file = open(filename, 'w')
    for items in wordlst:
        file.writelines(items + '\n')
    file.close()wordlst
```

Given that this works, this:

```py
def write_list_to_file(wordlst, filename):
    wordlst = ["No", "Time", "for", "this"]
    with open(filename+".txt",'w') as file:
        for items in wordlst:
            file.writelines(items + '\n')
```

Should too. Except that calling the function in the fashion of `write_list_to_file(wordlst, Idk)` returns no file. Fully aware that the list remains static I've tried a single parameter function in the same fashion, I.e :

```py
def makefile(filename):
    file = open(filename + ".txt", 'w')
    file.close()

makefile("Really")
```

This yields no file either somehow. Please do ignore the list's elements, i've been on this a lot longer than i care to admit and i couldn't find something that helps solve this particular issue. I've found countless solutions to make this happen, but not in the shape of a function taking any list and any file as input. In every case the exit code shows no error, so i'd at least expect a file to be create yet cant find any.

TLDR: tryin to make a write_list_to_file(wordlst,filename) function, must be missing stupidly obvious, help appreciated.

Edit: approved, the indention issue was only in this post though, the code was indented properly, made this in a hurry

Edit2: cf comments

Comment: Your `makefile()` function works fine for me when a string is passed to it (`makefile("Really")` instead of `makefile(Really)`, which will result in an error). You need to look for the file in the folder in which you're running the script. Your editor or IDE should tell you where that is.

Comment: yeah, i just ran your second function and it worked for me.  I had to change the indention though.

Comment: Turns out, it's a mix of failing to notice indentation for my function call was wrong and failing to notice "" were missing. Well, now i know. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code examples do not have the right indentation, which is important when writing python code.

Futhermore, `writelines()` takes in a list of strings. You iterate through your list and want to save each element on a seperate line - `write()` would be the right function for that.

Last, make sure to pass your filename as a string.

This code should work:

```
def write_list_to_file(wordlst, filename):
    with open(filename + '.txt', 'w') as file:
        for item in wordlst:
            file.write(item + '\n')

write_list_to_file(['element1', 'element2', 'element3'], 'tempfile')
```

Comment: In my test it worked even with writelines. I just can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Note for write vs writelines, couldn't understand why your version worked and mine did not. Turns out, it's a mix of failing to notice indentation for my function call was wrong and failing to notice "" were missing. Well, now i know. Thank you all.